# Adding satallite assemblies to XAP

Tags: silverlight, localization, xap

I have a situation where I need to add localised satallite assemblies to an existing XAP file.  This is in the context of a SharePoint webpart.

The problem is that when I add the de/Assembly.resources.dll and rebuild the XAP, it fails to load in the browser.  The mode of failure depends on how I attempt add the assembly to the AppManifest.xaml.  In some cases, it just shows nothing in the browser.  In others, it shows the loading spinner stuck at 0%.

My procedure is as follows:

Extract XAP

Extract the .resource from core webpart assembly

Convert to .resx

Translate

Rebuild as delay signed satallite assembly

copy to 'de' subfolder

Add to AppManifest

Rebuild XAP

Copy back to 14 hive

IISRESET

Clear browser cache

Test

The original assemblies are signed and so I have disabled assembly verification checking sn -Vr [star],[star] and have modified the registry to include 64bit and 32bit entries for verification checking.  Assembly verification check skipping has been proven on the same system in a non-Silverlight/XAP context.  The assemblies are built with the same .net version.  SharePoint timer service was restarted after sn -Vr to reload exception list for verification skipping.

I must be missing something, but I don't know what.

In one Silverlight localisation guide I saw that the .csproj contains a string of supported localisations - I doubt the original base assembly was build with any other cultures specified - could this be the problem?

I need to make 3rd party (I'm a software distributor) extensions to some OOTB components of the software I resell.  I have permission for this, and can even get my assemblies signed when the time is right, but I have no source access and any changes to the core component take a long time and a lot of effort - i.e. undesireable.

Assistance greatly appreciated.  I have this working already for some ASP.net apps and standard webparts - but this Silverlight based web-part remains a problem.

Many thanks.